# Como Fazer um Onclick em todas as Imagens da página?

Tags: javascript, html5

Gostaria de saber como faz para, ao clicar em QUALQUER imagem da página, ativar uma função.

Tentei das seguintes formas: 
1-

```
var imagez = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
        imagez.onclick = () =>{
      console.log(images);
    }
```

2-

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.janela');
//nesse caso, todas as imagens da tela teriam a classe "janela"
            images.onclick = () =>{
          console.log(images);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente você quer instalar um evento padrão para todas as imagens de uma página.

Para obter uma lista contendo todas as imagens da pagina use o método [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) de `document` que retornará uma lista de elementos presentes no documento que coincidam com o grupo de seletores especificado

```
document.querySelectorAll('img')
```

O objeto retornado por `document.querySelectorAll()` é uma [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NodeList) e apesar de `NodeList` não ser um [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), é possível ser iterada usando o método [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Para registrar um evento use o método [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener) para cada elemento imagem.

```js
//Assim que a página estiver carregada.
window.addEventListener("load", () => {

  //Para cada imagem da página.
  document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach((item) => {
   
    //Registra o evento click.
    item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      console.log(e.target);
    });

  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>HTML Image</h2>
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg?v=a010291124bf" alt="Trulli" width="100" height="66">
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/talent/logo-sotalent.svg?v=7b55c953cfdf" alt="Trulli" width="100" height="66">
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/sf/sf-logo.svg?v=5cfc8f44c8a3" alt="Trulli" width="100" height="66">

</body>

</html>
```